# How should I define a dynamic type in Typescript which should preserve the actual type entered by user

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I am creating a function that accepts some object in param with an interface like this `{[someKey]: (data: any) => any}`

```
type GenericRecord<value> = Record<string, value>

function createFunctionObject (funcObject: GenericRecord<(someParam: GenericRecord<any>, randomKey: string) => any>) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(funcObject).map(([key, fuc]) => [
      key,
      (param: GenericRecord<any>) => fuc(param[randomKey])
    ])
  );
}
```

The signature guarantees that the function `createFunctionObject` will accept an object of functions and will return an object of function.

Issue?

I want to preserve that the returned object will have the same keys as the passed object and also the return value of functions passed as arg will be the same as the return value of functions returned by `createFunctionObject`.

```
const {x, y, na } = createFunctionObject(
  { x: (param: GenericRecord<any>): number => state.x, y: (param: 
GenericRecord<any>): string => state.y, z: (param: 
GenericRecord<any>): string => state.z }, 'someKey'
);
```

this means I'll get 3 functions in return `{x, y, z}`, and destructuring with `x, y, na` should throw an error. Also, it should preserve that x will return a number and y, z should return a string. But the return type signature for `createFunctionObject` i am getting is `{ [k: string]: (state: GenericRecord<any>) => any; }`

Example of function:

```js
function createFunctionObject (funcObject, randomKey) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(funcObject).map(([key, fuc]) => [
      key,
      (param) => fuc(param[randomKey])
    ])
  );
}

const {a, b, c} = createFunctionObject({ a: (arg) => arg.a, b: (arg) => arg.b, c: (arg) => arg.c }, 'x')

console.log(a({x: {a: 20}})) // 20

console.log(b({x: {b: 30}})) // 30
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRpDLm) work for your use case?  Note that you can't just write `(arg) => arg.a` without some sort of type annotation on `arg`, unless you want it to just be of type `any`... I wrote `(arg: {a: number}) => arg.a` since that's how you seem to be using it.  Also, I can't tell if you are expecting your output functions to be called on the `a` or the `x` property of its input, as your example has both `fuc(param.a)` and `fuc(param.x)`.  Please consider modifying the code here to be a [mcve] and I'd be happy to write up an answer if it meets your needs.

Comment: @jcalz Your solution is perfect, `T[K] extends (arg: infer A) => infer R ? (arg: { x: A }) => R : never` does all the trick. Also, I have updated the code snippet, The output function can be called on any random key and object which will be provided by the user.

Comment: @jcalz, also one more question, how is defining the signature in a different declaration different from defining that signature while defining the function. Because when I do that I get an error for incompatibility ok keys in the returned object.

Comment: From what I have understood, this is how we overload signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's describe what `createFunctionObject` is supposed to do at the type level, without worrying about implementation.  Given an input `funcObject` of type `T` and an input `randomKey` of type `K`, where `T` represents an object whose values are functions of one argument, and `K` represents a `string` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), the output of `createFunctionObject` will be of the type `FunctionObject<T, K>`, defined as:

```
type FunctionObject<T extends Record<keyof T, (arg: any) => any>, K extends string> =
    { [P in keyof T]:
        T[P] extends (arg: infer A) => infer R ?
        (arg: { [Q in K]: A }) => R : never
    };
```

Observe that `FunctionObject<T, K>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), where we transform each of the function-valued properties of `T` into a new function type.  If the input function type is of type `(arg: A) => R`, for some `A` and `R`, then the output function type is of type `(arg: { [Q in K]: A}) => R`.  So if the input function expects an argument of type `A`, then the output function expects an argument of an object with a property of type `A` at the key `K`.

So the call signature of `createFunctionObject()` should look like this:

```
function createFunctionObject<
  T extends Record<keyof T, (arg: any) => any>, 
  K extends string
>(
    funcObject: T,
    randomKey: K
): { [P in keyof T]:
        T[P] extends (arg: infer A) => infer R ?
        (arg: { [Q in K]: A }) => R : never
    };
```

---

Now, while we can express this transformation at the type level, it's not really possible to have the compiler *verify* that your implementation conforms to this type signature.  The standard library typings for `Object.fromEntries()`, `Object.entries()`, and `Array.prototype.map()` are not detailed enough to do this, and even if we added our own type signatures for these, we'd find that the compiler would not be able to combine them in a way that avoid compiler errors.  So let's not even try to do this.

Instead, we will just tell the compiler not to worry about verifying the implementation too much.  One way to do this is with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in the implementation:

```
function createFunctionObject<
  T extends Record<keyof T, (arg: any) => any>, 
  K extends string
>(
    funcObject: T,
    randomKey: K
): FunctionObject<T, K> {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(funcObject).map(([key, fuc]) => [
            key,
            (param: Record<string, any>) => (fuc as Function)(param[randomKey])
        ])  // assert here
    ) as any; // assert here
}
```

But personally, in cases like this, I like to use an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with a  single call signature.  The compiler checks the implementation of overloaded functions more loosely than it checks the implementation of regular functions, and this is enough for us:

```
// call signature
function createFunctionObject<
  T extends Record<keyof T, (arg: any) => any>, 
  K extends string
>(
    funcObject: T,
    randomKey: K
): FunctionObject<T, K>;

// implementation (checked more loosely)
function createFunctionObject(
  funcObject: Record<string, Function>, 
  randomKey: string
) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(funcObject).map(([key, fuc]) => [
            key,
            (param: Record<string, any>) => fuc(param[randomKey])
        ])
    );
}
```

Either version should work.

---

Let's make sure that the call site behaves as you expect:

```
const { a, b, c } = createFunctionObject({
    a: (arg: { a: number }) => arg.a,
    b: (arg: { b: number }) => arg.b,
    c: (arg: { c: number }) => arg.c
}, "randomKey")
```

Note that I had to annotate the `a`, `b`, and `c` callback parameters as `{a: number}`, `{b: number}`, and `{c: number}`; if you left them unannotated as `a => arg.a`, the compiler would not know how to infer them, and this would end up falling back to `any`.  This is [usually a mistake](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny), so it's best to annotate things when the compiler cannot infer them.

Anyway, you can see that the resulting functions are callable and have the correct type signatures:

```
/* const a: (arg: {
    randomKey: {
        a: number;
    };
}) => number */
console.log(a({ randomKey: { a: 20 } })) // 20

/* const b: (arg: {
    randomKey: {
        b: number;
    };
}) => number */
console.log(b({ randomKey: { b: 30 } })) // 30
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEHkBGArCFAHgBUoIAPYCBAEwGcoAlQ9AJ1qIGsIR0AzKCQA0UABQBDNgHMAXFAkIQASigBeAHwKlG0QGlyVGgyj1gbVAmla1AWABQUJ1ADeUANoAFKJag8+giQAurIOzuFCXkGG1HSMkjLylvwQbFAAgqqaPggpaUxQAPxhEU4Jcq4eAIo5UHohGVAAvllaBfIIEABuqSVOTQDcDg78iCgYCFBIbBAS1PDIaJi4BMRklLEmLEjsnP4CQqLl8ooq6lqnunUxxoxmFlYaYn1Qo8grhMDyIi9sirToAC2el48j0DmU8gW42W+E+pH0GiG9mG9gA9AAqVHdGhQADuqGAAAsoMSIPRoID2NBaBBgBJUAAbCC0UngcmiPhwKaKADkwCgRIkPVJROgO0BYCZqSgiFpbDM-1Fc1F0AcqElzMBNHpS0mB2ms3mYz1HxQU0w-HYgMYwHQqrZkFMqGkCDmcBmqNATpgbCBAFEEOZUOTSDc4lAZhIAQhGSAPJ4-ZA2KAQSBRKcgjZKu49AA1WpkCSMfPuAAMQQapYAjNFBg4dggzK8-YDA8HyeooGbgAA6fit9sWTvFqBhja3SOzGNxhNJ1Kp3gZpRZsQ64f0eRRmfxkjuIKtWCDoMb0gaL3sqBDkP0M9dty52r7QJBAC0hS308ws9zoj39TrdxnyEIJkUbZt1xvLse17SCR0YM8xHQfBvkPFho2-EB0jYP4QCIa9QxIDQkVREYTQmKYo3mWhyNhVZgHHIwI22XZuF4A4RHEKQKlOQ9Ln0cMTHuSxrGeRxnDeJAe2+YRfn+IE0zBCEoVo7A4TWRFXF+OkPUmAcAxPG810M8kxEkntlF7QEJDAMTSicIhvAnCNgKIsQuC6T8MNjeMvD-KID3ODwPPLIIjjAeQWI4Ig9FETwpAkbVqAVUgog0UKNEPELazEMB3D+OgFN4A9olHcDgGUZQHCaBw0TRK8mCYLAmAAQlq+qSEvXlfQMjtb23TDgvYwJwsi1hotiqB4r+JLUlvPdXKzDK+JXDReR8RgEHQAVi3oF03RwZlSXtb1oG61SewROo1t7MQACYAGY7ruqqUXsAAZOleU27aoBwbaxTYBwMTRUj7EkvVKKNCBoVNdTgDMsZpOYcbOGEqxRFhiYrgKgFgVBUxgysVQXG04BdO7eH+2PPq7PsmC4PoRH3nhyzrNssQgKXV44CQQLsncF57L8Jchfs3KEsBMadmi9HpGXEBMqC0YkAlmb8vk-GQAPMWnB18SnGUZEaresjFgow05hhi74fSegKRTFlGM2Rgor2YbDi4xJtDObJ+OuZyhKJ0SXnM+GZLkwqtaU+xIVgG36KuvQtFJg2p3JthJhg-S2xMpndcp+jYLz5mpNZqybLETn-FEFX+a0QW0+FmuC-CNXEul1i5YVpXskRpAFEYLHMGUdvAQ1qO0314Xp+cVRR1OY2wfKyoJFEHBRAHpou0t41zboz4xFT8IJHkY5V46OBARwGUWiC7jezXl4cDP7j5DcF+oAQK+b7SO+-ZkL2DeLwkCv29m4UBX8f63z4oApA1VRAACJcZFRAIg16tUMQWibDtMBFRj7OBQdHLSTdnCnygdfVIyJwj1nsP-LQ39KFpBBg2TA9B0DMl7IydA0hJBH0jJrRSF8oB3TLM0ZolUoB1REWWVEmJsHNk-ufAhTgiFCJURET+jDf7UOcLQ+hFDf5QBYfYcCHCIBcJ4WIHA-C1EEw-vIB6Yjt4tFUNIpxYMgA)